# Display Wordpress posts per month dependant on url

Tags: wordpress, archive

If the url says this:

```
http://rascalcapac.com/2014/04/
```

I wan't to show posts only from april 2014. I have this, which I wan't to use:

```
query_posts( //here shall i filter ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this does'nt seem to be possible i wordpress, I fixed it with some php. The answer may be of some use for someone, so here goes:

```
$yearSlashMonth = trim($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI],'//');
$year = substr($yearSlashMonth,0,4);
$month = substr($yearSlashMonth,5,2);
```

Then:

```
query_posts( 'year=' . $year . '&monthnum=' . $month . '' ); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```